# Positive definite quadratic form defines nondegenerate positive inner product

Tags: quadratic-forms

The background to this question (which is not important for the actual question!) is that I'm working on something in geometric dynamics, specifically the Jacobi metric. To me it seems that one uses the kinetic energy of a dynamical system to define a pseudo-Riemannian metric on a manifold. However it is not clear to me whether this is actually always possible and if so how.

My question is whether a positive definite quadratic form (which I assume reasonably defined kinetic energies to be) induce positive nondegenerate or at least nondegenerate inner products. (For those in the know about geometrical mechanics this means whether a kinetic energy does indeed define a (pseudo-)Riemannian metric on a manifold).

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $S$ be a quadratic form on $V$ such that

1. $S(v)=0$ iff $v=0$
2. $S(v)>0$ for all $v\neq 0$

This defines a symmetric inner product, call it $g$, on $V$ as follows $g(v,w)=\frac{1}{2}(S(v+w)-S(v)-S(w))$

Under what circumstances is $g$ positive and/or nondegenerate?

Comment: Why don't you try to check the conditions? For example, $g(v,v) = 0.5 \cdot (S(2v) - S(v) - S(v)) = $...

Comment: Because I'm not sure how to do that.
Your example shows (I think) that $g$ must be nondegenerate, since $g(v,w)=0$ cannot be true for all $w$ if $v\neq 0$ since in that case $g(v,v)\neq 0$.
But how can you say anything about positivity in this way?

Comment: Well, we can relate $g(v,v)$ to $S(v)$, and we know that $S$ is a positive quadrature form...

Comment: Is it obvious that $S(v+w)>S(v)+S(w)$?

Comment: Aren't you trying to show that $g(v,v) > 0$ for all $v \ne 0$?

Comment: I thought positivity meant $g(v,w)>0$ for all $v,w\neq 0$ but after reading your comment I checked the definition... It's about having $g(v,v)>0$.
Thanks for your comments Christopher.

Comment: glad to be of help. Note that bilinear forms can never be always of one sign with both variables free, because if $g(v,w) > 0$, then $g(v,-w) < 0$.